# Script Python Error al ejecutar, modulos no encontrados

Tags: python, firebase, modulos

tengo un problema a la hora de ejecutar un script en Python

El error es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pao\Desktop\PES-Database-Scrapping-master\Scrapping.py", line 3, in <module>
    from firebase import firebase
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\firebase\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import python_jwt as jwt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_jwt'
```

El código que intento ejecutar es el siguiente:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from firebase import firebase
import random

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('pesdb-4cfb0.firebaseapp.com')

def player_scrap(link):
    url = link #Getting url from the link passed as paramater

    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    #Making a SOUP Object

    playerMainTable = soup.find('table',{'class':'player'}) #Fining Player Table (More than one table present in website)

    tr1 = playerMainTable.findAll('tr') #Finding all Rows
    allTables = tr1[0].find_all('table') #Get all table inside the first table row
    
    main_dict = {} #Dictionary to push to firebse

    for tables in allTables:
        dict = {} #Sub dict, to create dictionaries of dictionaries

        all_rows = tables.find_all('tr')
        #find all rows in sub table

        for i in all_rows:
            try:
                lable = i.find('th') 
                value = i.find('td')

                #Saving data according to structure of website

                print(lable.text, " ", value.text)

                dict[lable.text] = value.text #Put value into dict
                #result = firebase.put('/'+unique_num,lable.text,value.text)
            except:
                break
            main_dict.update(dict)
    result = firebase.post('/players',main_dict) ##POST IN FIREBASE
    print(result)



url = 'http://pesdb.net/pes2021/' #BASE URL

source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")

#CONVERTING WEBSITE CODE TO BS4 OBJECT

tables = soup.find('table',{'class': 'players'}) #Find all tables with class name 'players'

tr = tables.find_all("tr") #FINDING ALL ROWS in TABLE and Storing them in tr

for t in tr:
    td = t.find_all("td") 
    row = []
    c = 0
    for i in td:
        row.append(i.text) #GETTING EACH PLAYER
        if (c == 1):
            link = i.a.get('href')[1:] #LINK OF DETAILS OF EACH PLAYER
            player_scrap("http://pesdb.net/pes2021"+link) # Appending at the end of base url to jump to next page
        c = c + 1
    print(row)
```

Ya tengo todas las librerías instaladas desde firebase, requests, bs4.

Estoy ocupando la versión 3.9.5 de Python, ejecutando en Windows 10 Home.

El script lo que hace es obtener datos de una pagina en este caso pesdb lo cual obtiene datos de jugadores, equipos, estadisticas, etc.

Lo quiero utilizar para obtener datos de jugadores mediante python, otra versión que he encontrado es en JavaScript.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

PD. Otro error que me arroja es el siguiente:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
```

Comment: en el primer error parece que el moduloo de firebase no se instalo correctamente, puedes reinstalarlo o instalar el modulo que te dice `python_jwt`, del segundo error no tengo ni idea

Comment: Hola @Christian gracias por tu respuesta, ya instale la librería `python_jwt`


`Requirement already satisfied: jwcrypto>=0.8 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from python_jwt) (0.8)

Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.3 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from jwcrypto>=0.8->python_jwt) (3.4.7)

Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.3->jwcrypto>=0.8->python_jwt) (1.14.5)

Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=2.3->jwcrypto>=0.8->python_jwt) (2.20)`

Comment: Y sigues con el mismo error?

Comment: El segundo "error" no es un error sino un warning, y quizá lo que explica el warning sea la causa del primer error. Pero es solo una suposición.

Comment: Si el error sigue persistiendo, pero bueno me dijeron que desinstale e instale la 3.7 así que eso hare. Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Error arreglado, desinstale y volvi a instalar los modulos, luego pidio el Crypto lo cual lo solucione con

`pip uninstall crypto`
`pip uninstall pycrypto`
`pip install pycryptodome`